# getting number of likes on a post on facebook

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, sdk

I am new to Facebook programming. How do I get the number of likes on a post using ASP.net C#/c# sdk. I have given read_stream permission also.

```
var loginUrl = fb.GetLoginUrl(new
{

    client_id = "227454297425512",

    redirect_uri = "http://localhost:38368/FacebookSDKExample/Default.aspx",

    response_type = "code",

    scope = "email,user_likes,publish_stream,read_stream" // Add other permissions as needed

});
```

Please help.